# python dictionary from url

Tags: python, url, dictionary

I am trying to gather weather data from the national weather service and read it into a python script.  They offer  a JSON return, but they also offer another return which isn't formatted JSON but has more variables (which I want). This set of data looks like it is formatted as a python dictionary.  It looks like this:

```
stations={
KAPC:
{
'id':'KAPC',
'stnid':'92',
'name':'Napa, Napa County Airport',
'elev':'33',
'latitude':'38.20750',
'longitude':'-122.27944',
'distance':'',
'provider':'NWS/FAA',
'link':'http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mesowest/getobext.php?sid=KAPC',
'Date':'24 Feb 8:54 am',
'Temp':'39',
'TempC':'4',
'Dewp':'29',
'Relh':'67',
'Wind':'NE@6',
'Direction':'50&amp;#176',
'Winds':'6',
'WindChill':'35',
'Windd':'50',
'SLP':'1027.1',
'Altimeter':'30.36',
'Weather':'',
'Visibility':'10.00',
'Wx':'',
'Clouds':'CLR',
[...]
```

So, to me, it looks like its got a defined variable stations equal to a dictionary of dictionaries containing the stations and their variables.  My question is how do I access this data.  Right now I am trying:

```
import urllib
response = urrllib.urlopen(url)
r = response.read()
```

If I try to use the JSON module, it clearly fails because this isn't json.  And if I just try to read the file, it comes back with a long string of characters.  Any suggestions on how to extract this data?  If possible, I would just like to get the dictionary as it exists in the url return, ie `stations={...}`  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example URL that returns the data you want to parse so we can see the full output?

Comment: You can use RegExp ....to get your desired data.But it can also be done with help of JSON library

Comment: Here is an example url...http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mesowest/GmwXJList.php?extents=35.755148,-124.279663,38.813761,-119.720337&zoom=8&mapsize=830px,700px&density=1&

Answer (score 0):

See, As far I infer from the question, I assume that you have data in the form of text which in not a valid JSON data, So given we have a text like: `line = "stations={'KAPC':{'id':'KAPC', 'stnid':'92', 'name':'Napa, Napa County Airport'}}"` (say), then we can extract the dictionary by splitting it at the `=` symbol and then use the `eval()` method which initializes the dictionary variable with the required data.

```
dictionary_text = line.split("=")[1]

python_dictionary = eval(dictionary_text)

print python_dictionary
>>> {'KAPC': {'id': 'KAPC', 'name': 'Napa, Napa County Airport', 'stnid': '92'}}
```

The `python_dictionary` now behaves like a Python Dictionary with key, value pairs , and you can access any attribute using `python_dictionary["KAPC"]["id"]`

Comment: That is a really elegant solution, but I see two problems.  One is that the station id, in this example case `KAPC` is not in quotes, so this is likely to throw an error because it is not defined (?). And also, the records contain a URL field which contains a `sid=` request which messes everything up when trying to `split("=")`.